# condition for detecting string value in C++ template engine library inja (for SQL insertion of NULL)

Tags: c++, sql, null, template-engine

using the C++ template engine library

https://github.com/pantor/inja

In SQL I can INSERT a row in a database with a VARCHAR SQL type column named 'col1' with

```
std::string my_template = "INSERT INTO [my_table] (col1) VALUES ('my_value');"
```

To note that the SQL VARCHAR type requires to single quote

'my_value'

To insert a SQL NULL value, the single quotes are not specified

```
"INSERT INTO [my_table] (col1) VALUES (NULL);"
```

I have a template where the value is single quoted, and it allows to insert string values like

```
std::string insert_template =
"INSERT INTO [my_table] (col1) VALUES ( '{{my_value}}' )";

nlohmann::json json;
json["my_value"] = "some_value";
std::string sql = inja::render(insert_template, json);
```

calling the template with a tentative insertion of SQL NULL as

```
nlohmann::json json;
json["my_value"] = "NULL";
```

is incorrect because the string is single quoted resulting in a SQL insertion
of 'NULL' as a 4 character string and not an SQL NULL value

question

how can I make a condition to detect if the argument
'{{my_value}}' )

should be single quoted or not in the case the value is "NULL" ?

defining the template as (not single quoted)

```
std::string insert_template =
"INSERT INTO [my_table] (col1) VALUES ( {{my_value}} )";
```

would work for a NULL value but not a string

so, I would want something like (in pseudo INJA syntax)

```
std::string insert_template =
"INSERT INTO [my_table] (col1) VALUES ( 
{% if my_value == NULL %}
{{my_value}} 
{% else %}
'{{my_value}}'
{% endif %}
 )";
```

Is this possible to achieve somehow?

Comment: I wouldn't make `"NULL"` such a special case, as then you cannot search for this four-character string. Instead, I'd suggest to use `std::optional<std::string>` to represent nullability and writing a quick wrapper around `inja::render()` (if it doesn't provide it yet).

Answer (score 0):

this construct in the template chooses the quoted version or not depending on the value being "NULL"

```
nlohmann::json json4;
  json4["name"] = "NULL";
  std::string template5 = "INSERT INTO [my_table] (col1) VALUES ( \
  {%if name == \"NULL\"%}\
  {{name}}\
  {%else%}\
  '{{name}}'\
  {%endif%}\
  )";

  std::string rendered5 = inja::render(template5, json4);
  std::cout << rendered5 << std::endl;
```

rendered string is

```
INSERT INTO [my_table] (col1) VALUES (     NULL    )
```